# perl gracefully shut down child processes

Tags: perl, sigint

I'm new to perl. I have a process that uses poe::wheel::run to kick off multiple child processes. I'm trying to find a way to gracefully stop the wheel processes when SIG{INT} signal received.

I've been able to gracefully stop the child processes when it detects the parent isn't running.
I have a sig_int_handler that kills all processes (parent and children)

I cannot find a way for the child processes to detect and act on a sig_int_flag set to true.  Is this possible???

I'd like it to ...

- receive SIG{INT}
- set variable to sig_int_flag = 1 (or something)
- handler sends message that signal received then sleep for 30 seconds.
- after 30 seconds -- kill all processes.

meanwhile the wheel is on a loop that

- processes a file
- checks for and breaks out

  - if parent pid not detected or
  - if sig_int_flag == 1 (not working)
- otherwise processes next file

The idea is to give the wheel 30 seconds to finish what it's doing. if the child processes are not dead on their own -- we kill them.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: _handler sends message that signal received_ to whom?

Comment: To a log file just so I know this point of code was reached.

Comment: The `POE` framework provides all kinds of tools for precisely such things; probably way more than you need.  Look through its documentation, and seek pages with examples.   I don't use `POE` but I suspect that you don't need to write signal handlers by hand, but rather some callbacks for your objects...

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find a way for the child processes to detect and act on a sig_int_flag set to true. Is this possible???

For a child to see the same flag which the parent sets, the flag has to reside in shared memory.

Another way is to send a signal to the child where a handler sets the flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  "Another way is to send a signal to the child where a handler sets the flag".  Do you have examples or references. (Sorry to ask -- I'm terribly in-experienced!

Comment: You seem to already know all that's necessary. You have something which _kills all processes_, so you know how to send a signal to them, here you just don't send `SIGKILL`, but a signal which can be caught, e. g. SIGINT or SIGUSR1. And you _have a sig_int_handler_, so you know how to install a handler, here you just set the flag within, that you can check afterwards in the child's main loop.